# What's the most concise way in Python to group and sum a list of objects by the same property

Tags: python

I have a list of objects of type C, where type C consists of properties X,Y,Z, e.g., c.X, c.Y, c.Z

Now I want to perform the following task:

- Sum on the property Z of those objects that has the same value for property Y
- Output a list of tuples (Y, sum of Zs with this Y)

What's the most concise way?

Comment: To clarify, should the tuple contain (Y, sum of Zs with this Y)? or something else.

Comment: @sblom thanks yes your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `defaultdict` approach is probably better, assuming `c.Y` is hashable, but here's another way:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter
get_y = attrgetter('Y')
tuples = [(y, sum(c.Z for c in cs_with_y) for y, cs_with_y in 
           groupby(sorted(cs, key=get_y), get_y)]
```

To be a little more concrete about the differences:

- This approach requires making a sorted copy of `cs`, which takes O(n log n) time and O(n) extra space. Alternatively, you can do `cs.sort(key=get_y)` to sort `cs` in-place, which doesn't need extra space but does modify the list `cs`. Note that `groupby` returns an iterator so there's not any extra overhead there. If the `c.Y` values aren't [hashable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html), though, this does work, whereas the `defaultdict` approach will throw a `TypeError`.

  But watch out -- in recent Pythons it'll raise `TypeError` if there are any complex numbers in there, and maybe in other cases. It might be possible to make this work with an appropriate `key` function -- `key=lambda e: (e.real, e.imag) if isinstance(e, complex) else e` seems to be working for anything I've tried against it right now, though of course custom classes that override the `__lt__` operator to raise an exception are still no go. Maybe you could define a more complicated key function that tests for this, and so on.

  Of course, all we care about here is that equal things are next to each other, not so much that it's actually sorted, and you could write an O(n^2) function to do that rather than sort if you so desired. Or a function that's O(num_hashable + num_nonhashable^2). Or you could write an O(n^2) / O(num_hashable + num_nonhashable^2) version of `groupby` that does the two together.
- [sblom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9012923/344821) works for hashable `c.Y` attributes, with minimal extra space (because it computes the sums directly).
- [philhag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9012895/344821) is basically the same as sblom's, but uses more auxiliary memory by making a list of each of the `c`s -- effectively doing what `groupby` does, but with hashing instead of assuming it's sorted and with actual lists instead of iterators.

So, if you know your `c.Y` attribute is hashable and only need the sums, use sblom's; if you know it's hashable but want them grouped for something else as well, use philhag's; if they might not be hashable, use this one (with extra worrying as noted if they might be complex or a custom type that overrides `__lt__`).

Comment: When do you ever have something that's comparable but not hashable?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: lists, and just about anything else that's comparable but also mutable.

Comment: you could do `cs.sort(key=get_y)` without  `O(n)` extra space

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: good point, if you're willing to modify `cs`. Edited answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 9):

```
from collections import defaultdict
totals = defaultdict(int)
for c in cs:
  totals[c.Y] += c.Z

tuples = totals.items()
```

Comment: `defaultdict(int)` is prettier in my opinion.

Comment: `tuples = total.items()` is enough.

Comment: Is it possible to sum two properties ex. c.Z and c.Z2 at the same time with just one line code? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the list by y values, and then sum over their z values:

```
import collections
ymap = collections.defaultdict(list)
for c in listOfCs:
  ymap[c.Y].append(c)
print ([(y, sum(c.Z for c in clist)) for y,clist in ymap.values()])
```

Answer (score 3):

With [`pandas`](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/) it might be something like:

```
df.groupby('Y')['Z'].sum()
```

#### Example

```
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(dict(X=[1,2,3], Y=[1,-1,1], Z=[3,4,5]))
>>> df
   X  Y   Z
0  1  1   3
1  2  -1  4
2  3  1   5
>>> df.groupby('Y')['Z'].sum()
Y
-1    4
1     8
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
for c in cs:
  cnt[c.Y] += c.Z


print cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try run example bellow:

```
import collections
class Product():
    def __init__(self, name, amount, group = None):
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
        self.group = group

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s%r" % (self.__class__, self.__dict__)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%r" % self.__dict__
def print_amount_by_group():
    product_list = [Product('p1', 11, 'GRP3'), Product('p3', 11, 'GRP2'), 
        Product('p2', 11, 'GRP2'), Product('p25', 11)]
    prod_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for c in product_list:
        prod_dict[c.group].append(c)
    print([(key, sum(p.amount for p in product)) for key, product in         
    prod_dict.items()])
print_ammount_by_group()
```

result:
[('GRP3', 11), ('GRP2', 22), (None, 11)]