# Summing Attribute in a list of Python Objects

Tags: python, class, object, sum

Similar to ["What's the most concise way in Python to group and sum a list of objects by the same property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012864/whats-the-most-concise-way-in-python-to-group-and-sum-a-list-of-objects-by-the), I have a script in which I need to sum the attributes of list of objects.  However, my issue differs slightly.

I have a class of objects with attributes V, W, X, Y, and Z.  I need to sum attribute Z by iterating through and matching the attributes W, X, and Y with all other W, X, and Y attributes that are the same. Producing a new summed value that is indexed by W, X, and Y.

Here is the class for the objects:

```
class xb(object):
    def __init__(self, V, W, X, Y, Z):
       self.V = V
       self.W = W
       self.X = X
       self.Y = Y
       self.Z = Z

xbs = [xb()]
```

My initial thought was to do this through a series of nested if statements but this slows processing considerably and I'm sure my logic is all out of whack.

```
for xb in xbs:
    if xb.W == xb.W:
          if xb.X == xb.X:
              if xb.Y == xb.Y:
                  sum(xb.Z)
```

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post a tiny example of sample input and expected output, please? Also, what version of python are you using?

Comment: I think you should provide your "slow" version of the code.

Comment: My apologies, I am using Python 2.7

Comment: No need to apologize! and welcome to SO ;]

Comment: I appreciate the welcome.  I am actually a longtime user but this is my first post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
indexed_sums = defaultdict(int)
for o in xbs:
    indexed_sums[(o.W, o.X, o.Y)] += o.Z
```

For instance, if you start with (using your class definition of `xb`):

```
xbs = [xb(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
       xb(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
       xb(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
       xb(1, 4, 3, 4, 5),
       xb(1, 4, 3, 4, 3),
       xb(1, 2, 3, 9, 3)]
```

You end up with:

```
print dict(indexed_sums)
# {(4, 3, 4): 8, (2, 3, 4): 15, (2, 3, 9): 3}
```

Thus, you could get the sum for W, X, Y being 2, 3, 4 as:

```
indexed_sums[(2, 3, 4)]
# 15
```

---

Note that the `defaultdict` is doing very little work here (it's just a dictionary of counts that starts at 0 by default): the main thing is that you are indexing the `(o.W, o.X, o.Y)` tuples in a dictionary. You could have done the same thing without `defaultdict` as:

```
indexed_sums = {}
for o in xbs:
    if (o.W, o.X, o.Y) not in indexed_sums:
        indexed_sums[(o.W, o.X, o.Y)] = 0
    indexed_sums[(o.W, o.X, o.Y)] += o.Z
```

The `defaultdict` is just saving you two lines.

Comment: This method works perfectly, thanks a lot!  I am very unfamiliar with the collections module in general.  Can I use this same soft of methodology to compare the attributes of two classes?

Comment: @user2593375: See my edit. Don't get caught up in the `defaultdict`. The important part of this is that you're indexing a dictionary with those `(o.W, o.X, o.Y)` tuples- the fact that it's a defaultdict is just saving you a small amount of work.

Comment: @user2593375: Sure thing. Incidentally, you can [mark an answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Comment: Sorry to drag this out @David Robinson but do you know a way in which I can grab each index (o.W, o.X, o.Y) and their attributed summed value and use each of the four to populate a new set of four class attributes?

Comment: Actually I figured it out.  @David Robinson's solution produces a key that is a tuple.  Each tuple can be accessed using an index.  For example:
    for key, value in indexed_sums.iteritems():
        oW = key[0]
        oX = key[1]
        oY = key[2]
        indexed_sums_value = indexed_sums[key])

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very dirty hack of a one-liner:

```
{key:sum(g.Z for g in group)
    for key, group in 
    itertools.groupby(
        sorted(L, key=lambda p:tuple((operator.attrgetter(a)(p) for a in 'VWXYZ'))),
        key=lambda p:tuple(
                      (operator.attrgetter(a)(p) for a in 'VWXYZ')
                     )
    )
}
```

I don't recommend doing this at all (it's a pain to debug), but I think it's an interesting solution nonetheless